# Plotting in MATLAB crashes on values in exponential form

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I have stumbled upon a problem while trying to plot frequency response from experimental data. I have multidimentional array for amplitude (21*101) and arrays with frequencies' scanning start and end values. (21*1)

This code is working fine for data like: 5667 in the first cell, 5678 in the second, etc. But it crashes on data like 5.478e+5 and 4.999e+5:

```
A = load('Amplitude.mat');
Amp = A.Amplitude;
Fs = load('Fs.mat')
Fe = load('Fe.mat')

for i = 1:1:21
    f1 = Fs(i):10:Fe(i);//column 21*1
    grid on  
    y1 = plot(f1,AmpA1(i,:));  
    hold on
end
```

`f1` instaed of being in array (as in the case with the numbers in non-exponential form) 21*1 becomes a single value, which causes an error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

I tried to use sprintf() in order to change exponential form - didn't help.
Please, could you advice me how to fix it?

Files to test

- Amplitude: https://ufile.io/6gqi7
- Fs:https://ufile.io/g5d8u
- Fe:https://ufile.io/1afbj

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SardarUsama, I'm not sure I'm allowed to post this data.
I'll try to make a similar example and add it to the post.

Comment: @SardarUsama, added test files and updated the code.

Comment: Please try to use the matlab debugger to understand the problem better. It may be useful to ask a more specific and/or to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
Fs = load('Fs.mat')
Fe = load('Fe.mat')
```

will define the variables `Fs` and `Fe` as scalar structures with the variables from the respective mat files loaded as fields.  Indexing into `Fs` and `Fe` with any value greater than 1 will hence throw an error.

Try instead

```
s = load('Fs.mat'); Fs = s.Fs;
s = load('Fe.mat'); Fe = s.Fe;
```

(This assumes that the variables of interest inside the mat files are named `Fs` and `Fe` respectively.)